# Detect carriage return and overwrite printed content in python file output flow

Tags: python, shell, text

I'm running some deep learning code, which uses carriage return \r to rewrite the same line when printing training progress to shell.

```
...
Epoch #30: test_reward: 1262.060027 ± 400.441453, best_reward: 1467.428270 ± 381.180724 in #29
Epoch #31: 5001it [00:58, 86.14it/s, env_step=155000, len=1000, loss/actor=-51.270, loss/critic1=2.906, loss/critic2=2.892, n/ep=0, n/st=1, rew=1257.18]
...
```

This does save display space, but it doesn't work when running in background (such as using `nohup ... &`). After every epoch, 5000 lines are added to output file, ending up with a ~200MB text file after training.

Is it possible to customize a StringIO child class, which keeps an eye on \r in its buffer, such that if new \r comes with at least one \r or \n in buffer, writing position will be reset to the latest \r or \n?

Comment: Does the code have a way to disable the use of carriage return? That'd be easier than intercepting it.